# Can we generate a chart something like this with chart js?

Tags: charts, chart.js, linechart, angular13

I am currently trying to create a sleep tracking app using chart JS(4.1.1), but I can't seem to figure out how to correctly get it to work, and how to pass the data for it to display it correctly

I am expecting my sleep stage labels on the y-axis side and data representation on the x-axis, refer to the images...

I tried this option `indexAxis: 'y'` to show the labels on the y-axis, however, I'm seeing the labels on the y-axis but the chart is not loaded.

I added the relevant chart below, **is it even possible to generate a chart like this using chart JS(4.1.1)?**

*I tried with different data set combinations to get this chart but failed each time.*

**Dataset examples:**

```
datasets: [{
  data: [{x: 10, y: 20}, {x: 15, y: null}, {x: 20, y: 10}]
}]
```

---

```
datasets: [{
  data: [{x: 'awake', y: 20}, {x: 'rem', y: 10}]
}]
```

---

```
datasets: [{
  data: [{'data.key': 'one', 'data.value': 20}, {'data.key': 'two', 'data.value': 30}]
}]
```

[image: step line chart with linear gradient]

[image: step line chart with linear gradient padding]

Comment: One can't say much based on your `datasets`. Please post a full example so we may advise what you have to change. You may want to start simple from the data format and options of the [stepped line sample](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/stepped.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you, but i tried to recreate one of the example you gave.

Instead of inverting the axes, I put the different sleep types on the y axis.
Since chartjs doesn't really accept strings on the Y axis, I used a callback function to replace the labels on the Y axis with values from the yLabels array.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.1.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanva"></canvas>
```

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanva').getContext('2d');
var yLabels = ["REM", "Light", "Deep", "Awake"]

var cfg = {
  type:'line',
  data:{
    datasets: [{
      data: [
        {x: '0', y: '0'},{x: '1', y: '0'},{x: '1', y: '3'},{x: '4', y: '3'},{x: '4', y: '2'},{x: '5', y: '2'},{x: '5', y: '1'},{x: '8', y: '1'},{x: '8', y: '0'}
      ]
    }]
  },
  options:{
   scales: {
      y: {
        min:0,
        max:3,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1,
          callback: function(index) {
            return yLabels[index];
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var myChart = new Chart(ctx,cfg);
```

[Here's a codepen link](https://codepen.io/Frixionder/pen/dyQzOQJ)

Also, here's the [Chartjs ticks configuration documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/ticks.html) if you want to learn more about it